# capture the fwrite return value to a variable

Tags: php, fwrite

"fwrite() returns the number of bytes written, or FALSE on error. "

can the return value be captured in variable?

can the return values be added up for a total?

how can i capture the value of the return so i can use it later, like insert it into a data base.

this is the code i have

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r,MYSQL_NUM))
  {
   $data = implode("\t",$row) . "\n";
   echo fwrite($file,$data);
  }
```

Comment: `$bytesWritten = fwrite($file, $data)` isn't that hard.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the return value be captured in variable?

Yes.

```
$variable = fwrite($file, $data);
```

---

> Can the return values be added up for a total?

Yes, keep a running total and add to it in each iteration.

```
$total = 0;

foreach(...) {
    $total += fwrite($file, $data);
}
```

---

> How can I capture the value of the return so I can use it later, like insert it into a database?

Store it in a variable, then return it when ready to.

```
return $total;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood this should do it:

```
$filesizes = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r,MYSQL_NUM)) {
  $data = implode("\t",$row) . "\n";
  $filesizes[] = fwrite($file,$data);
}

$total = array_sum($filesizes);
```